# Moq Returning Same Result When Supplying Different Values To Returns()

Tags: c#, moq

I'm setting up a Mock for various test cases:

```
[Test]
[TestCase(0)]
[TestCase(1)]
[TestCase(4)]
public async Task Get_ReturnsAllUsers(int userCount)
{
    // Arrange
    var users = UserRepositoryTests.GenerateUsers(userCount);
    var extensionWrapper = new Mock<IDbConnectionExtensionsWrapper>();
    extensionWrapper
        .Setup(ex => ex.Get<User>(It.IsAny<IDbConnection>(), It.IsAny<IDbTransaction>(), It.IsAny<int>()))
        .Returns(Task.FromResult(users));

    var connection = new Mock<IDbConnection>();
    connection
        .Setup(conn => conn.BeginTransaction())
        .Returns(new Mock<IDbTransaction>().Object);

    var repository = new UserRepository(connection.Object, extensionsWrapper.Object);

    var usersFromRepository = await repository.Get();

    Assert.AreEqual(userCount, usersFromRepository.Count());
}
```

`GenerateUsers` looks like

```
private static IEnumerable<User> GenerateUsers(int count)
{
    using var crypto = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    var salt = new byte[16];
    crypto.GetBytes(salt);
    
    var random = new Random();
    var users = new List<User>();
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        users.Add(new User
        {
            Id = i,
            Username = Convert.ToString(i),
            Salt = salt,
            Hash = salt,
        });
    }

    return users;
}
```

And the relevant `repository` code looks like

```
public UserRepository(IDbConnection connection, IDbConnectionExtensionsWrapper wrapper)
{
    this.Connection = connection;
    this.ConnectionWrapper = wrapper;
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> Get()
{
    var users = await this.ConnectionWrapper
        .Get<User>(this.Connection);

    return users;
}
```

Finally `IDbConnectionExtensionsWrapper.Get(...)`

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> Get<T>(
    IDbConnection connection,
    IDbTransaction? transaction = null,
    int? timeout = null)
    where T : class
    => await connection.GetAllAsync<T>(transaction, timeout);
```

where `connection.GetAllAsync` belongs to `Dapper.Contrib.Extensions`.

The problem I have is that only the first `TestCase` succeeds. Every call to `IDbConnectionExtensionsWrapper.Get` returns an empty enumerable, despite the fact that I set the return in each case.

Comment: Your sample code doesn't show `extensionWrapper` being used. Is it being consumed anywhere?

Comment: How are you using `extensionWrapper` to set `this.ConnectionWrapper` in repository?

Comment: Edited the question to answer both your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a type mismatch that slipped my eyes. Since the signature of `IDbConnectionExtensionsWrapper.Get(...)` takes an `int?` and I was setting up the mock with `It.IsAny<int>()`, there was no suitable call to the method (it was never called).

The correct way to mock the method would be

```
extensionWrapper
    .Setup(ex => ex.Get<User>(It.IsAny<IDbConnection>(), It.IsAny<IDbTransaction?>(), It.IsAny<int?>()))
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(users));
```

which ends up making all test cases pass.